# How to get the right result for average from averages in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have report with totals.

In the end I have average values from route points.
I want to get the average value per route points.

[image]

results 
for example average for 2041 is 00:00:12

average for 2042 is 00:00:04

I want to get average from from 2041 & 2042

I received 00:00:12 which is not true..

For average and avg of avg i used the same expression :

```
=Format(
    TimeSerial(0,0,
        Round(
            IIf(sum(Fields!N_ANSWERED.Value)=0,
            0,
            sum(Fields!T_ANSWERED.Value) / iif(sum(Fields!N_ANSWERED.Value)=0,1,sum(Fields!N_ANSWERED.Value))
            )
        )
    ), 
"HH:mm:ss")
```

I expected ~ 00:00:08 as result.

Comment: I had similar problem in the past with total of totals from dynamic groups - in SSRS you have to use vba script in report body to get results you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An average of averages is rarely right.

For example, in group 2041 you appear to have higher call volume at lunch time, (12:00 to 13:00) as the calls take longer to answer, and lower call volume first thing in the morning (8:00). Let's say the average time to answer at 13:00 was 00:00:24 because 50 calls came in, but at 8:00 there was only one call which took 00:00:02 to answer. Now, the average of those two hours isn't `(00:00:24 + 00:00:02) / 2 = 00:00:13` because the amount of calls is very different in the two samples making up the average.

The real average is the average for that group multiplied by the number of calls in that group divided by the total calls  `(00:00:24 x (50/51)) + (00:00:02 x (1/51)) = 00:00:23.57`

If you are rounding to a precision of zero decimal places, that is still 00:00:24.

This is called the weighted average as each group's average influences the outcome depending on how many results are in the original calculation of the average for that group.

This is why your averages of 00:00:12 and 00:00:04 probably won't be 00:00:08, it will vary depending on how many calls are in each group. Now, if there are exactly the same number of calls in each group, then the average of averages will be the same as the weighted average (this is the only case where you would get 00:00:08).

The closer the total number of calls are in each group, the closer to the right result the average of averages will be, but it is an unreliable calculation.  Conversely, the more the number of results in each group varies, the more the weighted average will skew towards the average of the group that is more highly represented in the results.

Now, if there are a lot of results in the 2041 group and very few in the 2042 group then the 00:00:04 average result for 2042 will hardly influence the overall average, which may lead to the outcome where the result for 2041 overwhelms the result for 2042 and the overall average is the same as the average for 2041 within your level of precision and rounding, as per the example above.

The fact that there are several missing hours in the 2042 result set makes me think this is the case.

So your calculation looks correct - the sum of the time taken to call divided by the number of calls will give you the average for the groups and for the overall average. It is just that the average of averages won't be the same result because the groups aren't equally represented in the data used to calculate the overall average.

Based on your expression, your overall average looks accurate at 00:00:12.

Answer (score 1):

By referencing the rendered cell rather than the dataset filed you can so this quite simply.
1. Get the name of the cell containing the detailed average you have already calculated, let's assume this is called `textbox1`.

Then your expression is simply

```
=AVG(ReportItems!textbox1.Value)
```

Comment: Yep, this will give the result the OP expected (00:00:08), but may not be the result that is actually required on the report. It could be, depending on the question that is desired to to be answered. If it is "what is the average of the average time to answer by group" then this is the right answer. If the question is "what is the average time to answer overall" then the weighted average is what is required, which is the result the report currently gives (00:00:12). It depends on whether the readers of the report expect to see the average by call or by group.

Comment: I agree  Chris although I find lots of people looking to do these  calculations. I guess some people think it's more intuitive to read even though it's technically incorrect.

Comment: Thanks!Have a nice day!

Comment: It may not always be technically incorrect. For example, if you have the average mark for students studying a subject at schools then you could want to know what the average mark was _for schools_ in a district, in which case the average of averages is the correct answer. However, if you wanted to know the average mark _for students_ in a school district, then you want the weighted average. Mostly (and I think in the OP's case) the weighted average is what is required, but there are times when the average of averages is the correct solution.